# Is there a known pattern in functional programming when we return exact the same function?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming

I'm new in functional approach and today I'm writing some very useful, but really stupid simple function.

Can somebody point me to already known name of that approach?

Function impl:

```
public static <T, R> Function<T, R> getSomething(Function<T, R> f) {
    return f;
}
```

Dummy example:

```
UserController controller = Factory.getSomething(UserController::new)
            .compose(UserServiceImpl::new)
            .compose(UserDaoImpl::new)
            .apply(Factory.getConnection());
```

Assume that:

```
public class UserController {

    private UserService userService;

    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }
}

public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private UserDao userDao;

    public UserServiceImpl(UserDao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }
}

public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    private Connection connection;

    public UserDaoImpl(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }
}
```

Thank you and sorry for my newbie question.

Comment: Well this is simply the *identity* function `Function.identity()`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the problem is that `Function.identity()` doesn't accept function as argument. So we can't specify exact type. or maybe you can show simple example on this chain. Thanks

Comment: @Aominè sorry for that. I find the function above helpful for me, but at same time I'm sure that already known, because chain functions it's common case. So the question is because i don't know exact name of the approach i have decided to ask.

Comment: Why not simply write `new UserController(new UserServiceImpl(new UserDaoImpl(Factory.getConnection())))`? Looks much more readable to me, and it's also more concise.

Comment: @akhambir: not it accepts any type of function so you can pass a value or a function, ...

Comment: The `factory.getSomething(UserController::new)` method could also be replaced by `((Function<UserService, UserController>) UserController::new)`. What you have is called a factory method. It's just a bit special because its only point is to be able to make the compiler infer the type of `UserController::new`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem specified functions is not super flexible and reusable, I'm looking for fully generified and reusable function. actually my is that one =) `Function.identity()` looks really the same but not really nice because of undefined generic in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you asked for a “pattern in functional programming”, you have simply created an *identity function*. The fact that you have limited the argument and hence the return type to a function, doesn’t make it a special pattern, at least not in the FP world, where functions are values and so, passing a function to an identity function is noting special.

The reason you couldn’t use `Function.identity().apply(…)` here, lies in the way functions have been added (or haven’t been added from that point of view) to Java, requiring an actual functional interface as target type, and the inability of inferring such a type through a chain of method invocations. Since this is Java specific, it can’t have a name outside the Java world, as true FP languages don’t need such a construct.

To demonstrate the point, you could use

```
UserController controller = Function.<Function<UserService,UserController>>identity()
    .apply(UserController::new)
    .compose(UserServiceImpl::new)
    .compose(UserDaoImpl::new)
    .apply(Factory.getConnection());
```

instead, solving the issues of Java’s type system via explicit types. So your custom method just simplifies the use of Java’s type system with an identity function in this context, which is no general FP pattern beyond using an identity function.

As a side note, I don’t consider this entire construct an improvement over

```
UserController controller = new UserController(
    new UserServiceImpl(new UserDaoImpl(Factory.getConnection())));
```

In fact, it took me several minutes to understand what your code actually does. So, speaking of patterns, 
this could be called *method reference overuse* or *overuse of functional constructs* (both being Java specific pattern). Also this pattern of wrapping something four times may have a name on its own…